# make 1 Row of a table fixed

Tags: html, css

i have a HTML table in which i want to make 1st Row fixed while i scroll, I'm able to make fixed Header Row but i also wanted my 1st Row of my table also be stay fixed. Its been 2 days I'm trying' with no success. Anybody out there had run into this kind a problem ?

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Header 1</th><th>Header 2</th> // this i have fixed already
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>....</tr> // this row i want to make fixed while i scroll.
      <tr>....</tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fosterz/zfUr8/) till now i'hv got this from net

Comment: Check out [Chris Coyer's article on persistent headers](http://css-tricks.com/persistent-headers/).

Comment: i already made my headers fixed. i want my 1st Row to be stay fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table can have more than one `tbody` elements, so you can add this fixed row to first tbody, and rest rows to the second tbody. Then is just some play with css to set it right.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sMMZ9/4/

Demo is based on [this solution](http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html)

Comment: Hi, one more favour. Now my 1st row is fixed, when the content of the columns are getting bigger the width of the cell is also increasing n thus making row width disturbed, i tried putting `table-layout:fixed;` but no use

Comment: There was wrong widths, and there might be a problem. Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/sMMZ9/4/

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert first row inside the `<thead>` element and apply the same css as you have applied for th element:-

```
<thead class="fixedHeader">
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <th><a href="#">Header 1</a></th>
        <th><a href="#">Header 2</a></th>
        <th><a href="#">Header 3</a></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

***CSS***

```
html > body thead.fixedHeader td {
    width: 200px;
}
```

You can also add border as per your design.Hope it'll help you for sure.

Comment: if i do that, my columns widths of 1st Row will mess up, and my each column width are getin' from db.

Comment: This do the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

How's this:

```
.scrollContent > tr:first-child{
    position: fixed;
}
```